# Insertion Sort for Singly Linked List [EXTERNAL]

Tags: sorting, singly-linked-list, insertion-sort, external-sorting

I'm not sure where to start, but this is messy. Basically I need to write an Insertion Sort method for singly linked list - which causes enough problems, because usually for Insertion Sort - you're supposed to go through array/list elements backwards - which implementing into a singly linked list seems pointless, because the point of it - is that you're only capable of going forwards in the list and in addition to that -> I need to execute "swap" operations externally, which I do not completely understand how to perform that while using list structure.

This is my ArrayClass and Swap method that I used:

```
class MyFileArray : DataArray
{
    public MyFileArray(string filename, int n, int seed)
    {
        double[] data = new double[n];
        length = n;
        Random rand = new Random(seed);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            data[i] = rand.NextDouble();
        }
        if (File.Exists(filename)) File.Delete(filename);
        try
        {
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(filename,
           FileMode.Create)))
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
                    writer.Write(data[j]);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    public FileStream fs { get; set; }
    public override double this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            Byte[] data = new Byte[8];
            fs.Seek(8 * index, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            fs.Read(data, 0, 8);
            double result = BitConverter.ToDouble(data, 0);
            return result;
        }
    }
    public override void Swap(int j, double a)
    {
        Byte[] data = new Byte[16];
        BitConverter.GetBytes(a).CopyTo(data, 0);
        fs.Seek(8 * (j + 1), SeekOrigin.Begin);
        fs.Write(data, 0, 8);
    }
}
```

And this is my Insertion Sort for array:

```
public static void InsertionSort(DataArray items)
    {
        double key;
        int j;
        for (int i = 1; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            key = items[i];
            j = i - 1;
            while (j >= 0 && items[j] > key)
            {
                items.Swap(j, items[j]);
                j = j - 1;
            }
            items.Swap(j, key);

        }
    }
```

Now I somehow have to do the same exact thing - however using Singly Linked List, I'm given this kind of class to work with (allowed to make changes):

```
class MyFileList : DataList
{
    int prevNode;
    int currentNode;
    int nextNode;
    public MyFileList(string filename, int n, int seed)
    {
        length = n;
        Random rand = new Random(seed);
        if (File.Exists(filename)) File.Delete(filename);
        try
        {
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(filename,
           FileMode.Create)))
            {
                writer.Write(4);
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
                {
                    writer.Write(rand.NextDouble());
                    writer.Write((j + 1) * 12 + 4);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    public FileStream fs { get; set; }
    public override double Head()
    {
        Byte[] data = new Byte[12];
        fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        fs.Read(data, 0, 4);
        currentNode = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
        prevNode = -1;
        fs.Seek(currentNode, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        fs.Read(data, 0, 12);
        double result = BitConverter.ToDouble(data, 0);
        nextNode = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 8);
        return result;
    }
    public override double Next()
    {

        Byte[] data = new Byte[12];
        fs.Seek(nextNode, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        fs.Read(data, 0, 12);
        prevNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = nextNode;
        double result = BitConverter.ToDouble(data, 0);
        nextNode = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 8);
        return result;
    }
```

To be completely honest - I'm not sure neither how I'm supposed to implement Insertion Sort nor How then translate it into an external sort. I've used this code for not external sorting previously:

```
       public override void InsertionSort()
    {
        sorted = null;
        MyLinkedListNode current = headNode;
        while (current != null)
        {
            MyLinkedListNode next = current.nextNode;
            sortedInsert(current);
            current = next;
        }
        headNode = sorted;
    }

    void sortedInsert(MyLinkedListNode newnode)
    {
        if (sorted == null || sorted.data >= newnode.data)
        {
            newnode.nextNode = sorted;
            sorted = newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            MyLinkedListNode current = sorted;
            while (current.nextNode != null && current.nextNode.data < newnode.data)
            {
                current = current.nextNode;
            }
            newnode.nextNode = current.nextNode;
            current.nextNode = newnode;
        }
    }
```

So if someone could maybe give some kind of tips/explanations - or maybe if you have ever tried this - code examples how to solve this kind of problem, would be appreciated!

Comment: insertion sort in a linked list is no problem.  You build the sorted list linked backwards and reverse it when you're done.  I have no idea what you could mean about externally sorting a linked list, though.  That doesn't make any sense, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually have solved this fairly recently.

Here's the code sample that you can play around with, it should work out of the box.

```
public class SortLinkedList {

 public static class LinkListNode {
    private Integer value;
    LinkListNode nextNode;

    public LinkListNode(Integer value, LinkListNode nextNode) {
        this.value = value;
        this.nextNode = nextNode;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public LinkListNode getNextNode() {
        return nextNode;
    }

    public void setNextNode(LinkListNode nextNode) {
        this.nextNode = nextNode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.value.toString();
    }
}

public static void main(String...args) {
    LinkListNode f = new LinkListNode(12, null);
    LinkListNode e = new LinkListNode(11, f);
    LinkListNode c = new LinkListNode(13, e);
    LinkListNode b = new LinkListNode(1, c);
    LinkListNode a = new LinkListNode(5, b);
    print(sort(a));
}


public static void print(LinkListNode aList) {
    LinkListNode iterator = aList;
    while (iterator != null) {
        System.out.println(iterator.getValue());
        iterator = iterator.getNextNode();
    }
}

public static LinkListNode sort(LinkListNode aList){
    LinkListNode head = new LinkListNode(null, aList);
    LinkListNode fringePtr = aList.getNextNode();
    LinkListNode ptrBeforeFringe = aList;
    LinkListNode findPtr;
    LinkListNode prev;
    while(fringePtr != null) {
        Integer valueToInsert = fringePtr.getValue();
        findPtr = head.getNextNode();
        prev = head;
        while(findPtr != fringePtr) {
            System.out.println("fringe=" + fringePtr);
            System.out.println(findPtr);
            if (valueToInsert <= findPtr.getValue()) {
                LinkListNode tmpNode = fringePtr.getNextNode();
                fringePtr.setNextNode(findPtr);
                prev.setNextNode(fringePtr);
                ptrBeforeFringe.setNextNode(tmpNode);
                fringePtr = ptrBeforeFringe;
                break;
            }
            findPtr = findPtr.getNextNode();
            prev = prev.getNextNode();
        }
        fringePtr = fringePtr.getNextNode();
        if (ptrBeforeFringe.getNextNode() != fringePtr) {
            ptrBeforeFringe = ptrBeforeFringe.getNextNode();
        }
    }
    return head.getNextNode();
 }
}
```

From a high level, what you are doing is you are keeping track of a fringe ptr, and you are inserting a node s.t. the it is in the correct spot in the corresponding sublist.

For instance, suppose I have this LL.

3->2->5->4

The first iteration, I have fringePtr at 2, and I want to insert 2 somewhere in the sublist that's before the fringe ptr, so I basically traverse starting from head going to the fringe ptr until the value is less than the current value. I also have a previous keeping track of the previous ptr (to account for null, I have a sentinel node at the start of my traversal so I can insert it at the head).

Then, when I see that it's less than the current, I know I need to insert it next to the previous, so I have to:

1. use a temporary ptr to keep track of my previous's current next.
2. bind previuos's next to my toInsert node.
3. bind my toInsert node's next to my temp node.

Then, to continue, you just advance your fringe ptr and try again, basically building up a sublist that is sorted as you move along until fringe hits the end.

i.e. the iterations will look like

```
1. 3->2->5->4
      ^
2. 2->3->5->4
         ^
3. 2->3->5->4
            ^
4. 2->3->4->5 FIN.
```